p values one vs two tailed Kendall's tau, Spearman's rho, Pearson r
For Pearson correlations one can easily determine the p values for one tailed tests from the p values of two tailed tests by
p1tailed, predicted direction = 1/2 * p2tailed 
p1tailed, opposite direction = 1 - 1/2 * p2tailed
However, for Kendall's tau and Spearman's rho (exact values [not approximated], small samples) this is only the case for the predicted direction, but not if the effect is in the opposite direction.

Another way to state my problem, why does 1 = p1tailed, predicted direction + p1tailed, opposite direction holds true for Pearson but not for Kendall and Spearman (at least for small N and exact values)?

Unless you have ties  the exact null distribution of rank based correlation is still symmetric since it's a function of ranks (for a null of not being related) so unless there are ties 2 tailed p should be exactly  twice the 1 tailed p when in the predicted direction. However that's not the same thing as why " 1 = p1tailed, predicted direction + p1tailed, opposite direction" doesn't  hold ... since theyre discrete statistics so you count the 'exactly  as extreme' case in each
